# casting an int array to a double to calculate percentage

Tags: java, arrays, casting

I am writing a beginner program using arrays, math.random and and random generator to calculate the sum of 2 die rolling a certain amount of times.

I am trying to calculate the percentage of times a sum shows up and need 2 decimal places. Is there a way to cast(?) and array so that it appears with 2 decimal places?

Also, when I print on screen the program it shows 120 times each sum. I dont understand why

This is what I have so far:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Die {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        int faces;
        int face1;
        int face2;
        int face3;
        int face4;
        int times;
        int index;
        int sum;



        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random rand = new Random();

        System.out.println("%-0-1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-0-1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-0-%");
        System.out.println("%\t\t\t\t\t    %");
        System.out.println("%  How good is the Random Number Generator  %");
        System.out.println("%\t\t\t\t\t    %");
        System.out.println("%-0-1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-0-1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-0-%");

        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("What is the number of sides of each die? ");
        faces = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.print("How many times do you want to roll the dice ?");
        times = scan.nextInt();


        int[]rollCount = new int[(faces*2) + 1];

        for (int i = 0; i<rollCount.length; i++)
            rollCount[i] = 0;

                int dice1=faces;
                    for (int k=1; k<=dice1; k++){
                        int dice2=faces;
                            for (int r=1; r<=dice2; r++){

                    rollCount[k+r]++;

                    for (int roll = 0; roll <times; roll++){
        }

    }
}




        int[]rollCountRand = new int[(faces*2) + 1];
        for (index = 0; index <rollCountRand.length; index++)
            rollCountRand[index] = 0;


        for (int roll = 0; roll<=times; roll++){
            face1 = 1 + rand.nextInt(faces);
            face2 = 1 + rand.nextInt(faces);
            rollCountRand[face1 + face2]++;
        }


        int[]rollCountMath = new int [(faces*2)+1];

        for (int i=0; i<rollCountMath.length; i++)
            rollCountMath[i] = 0;

        for (int j=0; j<=times; j++){

            face3 = (int)(faces* Math.random() + 1);
            face4 = (int)(faces* Math.random() + 1);
            sum = face3 + face4;
            rollCountMath[sum]++;
        }



        for (int r = 2; r <rollCount.length; r++){

             int percent = (rollCount[r] / ((faces*faces)*100));

        for (int k = 2; k <rollCountRand.length; k++){

             int percentOne = rollCountRand[k] / (times/100);

            for (int q = 2; q <rollCountMath.length; q++){

                int percentTwo =rollCountMath[q] / (times/100);





        System.out.print(r + "\t( " + rollCount[r] + ")"  + "\t" + "%" + percent + "\t" + k + "\t( " + rollCountRand[k]+")" + "\t"+"%"+percentOne + "\t" + q + "\t( " + rollCountMath[q]+")" + "\t" + "%"+percentTwo);
            System.out.println();
```

Thank You!

Comment: You can't "cast" an entire array from int to double.  The values in the array are `int` values and won't magically change even in a language such as C where the cast would actually be allowed (or at least not cause a compile error).  If you want float values make your array of elements of a float type.

Comment: Note, however, that you can keep integers that are 100 times your % value and insert the decimal point yourself (using character manipulation).  But you will sometimes get unexpected rounding/truncation with this approach.

Comment: It's not clear why you have the two different ways of rolling dice -- the first, using Random.nextInt, is the better, and keeps you from unnecessarily dealing with floating point.  (In fact, why do you seem to be doing the exact same thing twice?)

Comment: Note that it's not necessary to pre-zero your arrays -- they get set to zero when they're created.

Answer (score 2):

You can't directly cast `int[]` to `double[]`, but you can cast each element as you process it, for example where you calculate the percentage, you could write `int percentTwo = (int)Math.round((double)rollCountMath[q] / (times/100.0));`.

As for loop counts, it looks like your code posted here is lacking some closing braces (maybe it's just a formatting error when you pasted the code), so it's hard to say how it would behave if the braces were in place.